# Variation of nested interval theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is the question I'm trying to solve:

> Suppose that $(u_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and $(v_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ are two
> sequences of numbers such that $u_1 < u_2 < u_3 < ...$ and $v_1 > v_2
> > v_3 > ...$ Suppose also that for every $n$, $u_n < v_n$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (v_n - u_n) = 0$. Show that there is a unique
> number $c$ such that for every $n$, $u_n < c < v_n$.

Also as a hint to the question, it's mentioned that I should use nested
interval theorem to solve it.

Now from nested interval theorem, I know that

$u_n \leq c \leq v_n$

Also from our assumptions from the question we know that $u_n < v_n$.

Now I'm stuck after this step. I see that there is two possible
things I can conclude from $u_n < v_n$. It can be either of $u_n \leq
c < v_n$ or $u_n < c \leq v_n$. But I'm not sure how to prove $u_n < c
< v_n$.

Comment: This is just by definition. We have $$u_n<u_{n+1}\leq c\leq v_{n+1}<v_n$$ Done!!

Comment: The same argument also shows that the limit of a strictly monotone sequence is never equal to any of its terms. For strictly increasing sequence it is greater than the terms and for strictly decreasing sequence it is less than the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step you need come from the fact that $u_1<u_2<u_3<\ldots$.

For every $n$, $u_n< c$. This is proven by contradiction. If there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $u_k=c$, then
$$c=u_k<u_{k+1}$$
This contradict the assumption of $u_{k+1}\leq c \leq v_{k+1}$

The same argument show that $c<v_n$, for all $n$.

Comment: How does it contradict the assumption of $u_{k+1}<c<v_{k+1}$ ? Instead, doesn't it contradict with $u_{k+1} \leq c \leq v_{k+1}$ ?

Comment: @Sibi You are right, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can’t exist $n$ such that $u_n=c$ as this would imply $u_n=c \lt u_{n+1}$ and therefore $c \notin (u_{n+1}, v_{n+1})$ in contradiction with the conclusion of the nested interval theorem. In a similar  way, $c \lt v_{n+1}$.

So $u_n \lt c \lt v_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Also $c$ is unique as the lengths of the interval is converging to zero.